# How can I get parens in a URL using the Doxia APT format?

Tags: doxia

I am using the APT format to create documentation on a maven project. I am trying to link to a  JavaDoc method description, which URL contains a parentheses.

For example, the url

```
http://myjavadoc/methodname(java.lang.string)
```

Becomes

```
http://myjavadoc/methodnamejava.lang.string
```

Trying to use URL-encoding produces a similar result in that the percent symbol is stripped out.

```
http://myjavadoc/methodname28java.lang.string29
```

In both cases, escaping the character with a backslash has no effect.

Does anyone know how to get parens (or percents) to be interpreted through apt correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You should mention your doxia version.

Anyway both methods worked for me with doxia 1.6

```
Link to {{{http://myjavadoc/methodname(java.lang.string)}http://myjavadoc/methodname(java.lang.string)}}.

Link to {{http://myjavadoc/methodname(java.lang.string)}}.
```